# Trait objects from references

Tags: rust, trait-objects

The below is (roughly) the trait object example taken from the rust book chapter 17.2. For my use case, I want to continue to use `button` and `select_box` after creating `screen` (see the commented out `println!()` after declaring `screen`), however I am not able since `button` and `select_box` are moved into `screen`. To me it seems the solution is to have `screen` borrow, instead of take ownership, of `select_box` and `screen`. However, I can't work out how to do this. I have tried creating boxes from references like:

```rust
let screen = Screen {
    components: vec![Box::new(&select_box), Box::new(&button)],
};
```

but this generates errors like:

```
the trait `Draw` is not implemented for `&SelectBox`
```

```rust
fn main() {
    let select_box = SelectBox {
        width: 75,
        height: 10,
        options: vec![
            String::from("Yes"),
            String::from("Maybe"),
            String::from("No"),
        ],
    };
    let button = Button {
        width: 50,
        height: 10,
        label: String::from("OK"),
    };
    let screen = Screen {
        components: vec![Box::new(select_box), Box::new(button)],
    };
    // println!("button width: {}", button.width);
    screen.run();
}

trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}

struct Screen {
    components: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
}

impl Screen {
    fn run(&self) {
        for component in self.components.iter() {
            component.draw();
        }
    }
}

struct Button {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    label: String,
}

impl Draw for Button {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("Button({}, {}, {})", self.width, self.height, self.label)
    }
}

struct SelectBox {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    options: Vec<String>,
}

impl Draw for SelectBox {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!(
            "SelectBox({}, {}, {})",
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.options.join(";")
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is to have a blanket implementation for `&T` and `&mut T` where `T: Draw`:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized + Draw> Draw for &'_ T {
    fn draw(&self) {
        <T as Draw>::draw(&**self)
    }
}
impl<T: ?Sized + Draw> Draw for &'_ mut T {
    fn draw(&self) {
        <T as Draw>::draw(&**self)
    }
}
```

However, then you get another error:

```rust
error[E0597]: `select_box` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:35
   |
17 |         components: vec![Box::new(&select_box), Box::new(&button)],
   |                          ---------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                          |        |
   |                          |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          cast requires that `select_box` is borrowed for `'static`
...
21 | }
   | - `select_box` dropped here while still borrowed

error[E0597]: `button` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:58
   |
17 |         components: vec![Box::new(&select_box), Box::new(&button)],
   |                                                 ---------^^^^^^^-
   |                                                 |        |
   |                                                 |        borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                 cast requires that `button` is borrowed for `'static`
...
21 | }
   | - `button` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This is because `dyn Trait` is actually `dyn Trait + 'static`. You need to add a lifetime parameter:

```rust
struct Screen<'a> {
    components: Vec<Box<dyn Draw + 'a>>,
}

impl Screen<'_> {
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b9f71696dfe6c431cf58801b783e146).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Rc` instead of `Box` to make it possible for `screen` and the main function to reference the two components `select_box` and `button` at the same time.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
fn main() {
    let select_box = Rc::new(SelectBox {
        width: 75,
        height: 10,
        options: vec![
            String::from("Yes"),
            String::from("Maybe"),
            String::from("No"),
        ],
    });
    let button = Rc::new(Button {
        width: 50,
        height: 10,
        label: String::from("OK"),
    });
    let screen = Screen {
        components: vec![select_box.clone(), button.clone()],
    };
    println!("button width: {}", button.width);
    screen.run();
}

trait Draw {
    fn draw(&self);
}

struct Screen {
    components: Vec<Rc<dyn Draw>>,
}

impl Screen {
    fn run(&self) {
        for component in self.components.iter() {
            component.draw();
        }
    }
}

struct Button {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    label: String,
}

impl Draw for Button {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!("Button({}, {}, {})", self.width, self.height, self.label)
    }
}

struct SelectBox {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    options: Vec<String>,
}

impl Draw for SelectBox {
    fn draw(&self) {
        println!(
            "SelectBox({}, {}, {})",
            self.width,
            self.height,
            self.options.join(";")
        )
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48eca57f84c4041924781b826eed2653)

Here is the output:

```
button width: 50
SelectBox(75, 10, Yes;Maybe;No)
Button(50, 10, OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

Trait objects can be used via *any* pointer type (like references, `Rc`, `Arc`, etc.), not just `Box`. So, if you want `Screen` to borrow components, you can simply store *references* to the `Draw` trait objects representing the components:

```
struct Screen<'c> {
    components: Vec<&'c dyn Draw>,
}

impl Screen<'_> {
    fn run(&self) {
        for component in self.components.iter() {
            component.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94b13e362e22d6f4c0ef54e372fbd531)